# PowerShell Core and AppX package management

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell 6.2 preview at the moment. In my script I am trying to do stuff with Windows 10 apps. To be able to use commands like `Get-AppxPackage`, I need to import Windows modules from previous PowerShell like so:

```
Import-Module C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Appx\Appx.psd1 -SkipEditionCheck 

Import-Module C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\dism\dism.psd1 -SkipEditionCheck
```

Does PowerShell core has its own modules to work with this? I found `Get-Package` for example, but that does not give me anything.

Comment: The easiest way is to use WIndows Powershell 5.1 and not Powershell Core. But there is a way using Core, have a look at the WindowsCompatibiity module: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/11/15/announcing-general-availability-of-the-windows-compatibility-module-1-0-0/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Interesting link that is :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is one of the top search results for *PowerShell Core Get-AppxPackage*, I'm going to take the information from the link provided in the comments and provide an answer, with example.

As LangsGalgEnRad pointed out in the comments, it's easiest just to do this from Windows PowerShell, but ultimately that's just-shy-of-deprecated at this point, with Microsoft stating that there are to be no more fixes or changes other than critical security issues.  That said, it's still (afaik) universally available in Windows installations.

But for those of us who want to follow Microsoft's advice to use PowerShell Core, LangsGalgEnRad also points out in the comments the [`WindowsCompatibility` module](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/11/15/announcing-general-availability-of-the-windows-compatibility-module-1-0-0/) from Microsoft.  Reading the blog post, this *seems* a bit safer than importing a Windows module (e.g. `AppX`) from PowerShell Core, since among other things ...

> `WindowsCompatibility` is very careful to not overwrite native PowerShell core commands.

To install from PowerShell Gallery:

```
Install-Module WindowsCompatibility
```

Example usage for `AppX`:

```
Import-Module WindowsCompatibility
Import-WinModule AppX
Get-AppxPackage
```

Comment: 'Import-Module' Appx is suggested.  but still doesnt work for me.   I resorted to using non-powershellcore, e.g. powershell 5 and under