# Get-appxpackage : The 'Get-appxpackage' command was found in the module 'Appx', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: windows, powershell

i completely cant open start menu, cortana and windows icon tray.

the problem is `"Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost" and "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana" applications need to be installed correctly.`

i've read  some solution. i want to reinstall the application by using powershell
but when i run `Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% {add-appxpackage -register -disabledevelopmentmode ($_.installlocation + "\appxmetadata\appxbundlemanifest.xml")}` it gives me error like this

> Get-appxpackage : The 'Get-appxpackage' command was found in the module 'Appx', but the module could not be loaded.
>   For more information, run 'Import-Module Appx'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% {add-ap ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-appxpackage:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

[image]

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to run `Get-AppxPackage` on PowerShell 7

Comment: It suggests to run `Import-Module Appx` to get a more detailed error message. What does it say?

Comment: There is another question about why this does not work with PowerShell Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950968/powershell-core-and-appx-package-management
This seems not be the cause here, as the screenshot looks like PowerShell 5.

Comment: Could you _do the thing_, please, and run `ipmo Appx`, and then paste the output as text, not as a screenshot? You can use triple-backticks to format it.

Comment: Check that you have service **AppXSvc** running